# Axes labels on bar charts

Tags: charts, label

I have written code to produce charts but now need to include labels on the x- and y-axes. Suggestions on how to include labels will be appreciated. Using the code:

```
f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)

axarr[0].bar(ind, y1, width, color='white', edgecolor='black', bottom=y3)

axarr[0].bar(ind, y2, width, color='yellow', edgecolor='black')

axarr[0].bar(ind, y3, width, color='black', edgecolor='black')

axarr[0].set_title('Growth in Resistance')


axarr[1].bar(ind, y4, width, color='white', edgecolor='black', bottom=y6)

axarr[1].bar(ind, y5, width, color='yellow', edgecolor='black')

axarr[1].bar(ind, y6, width, color='black', edgecolor='black')

axarr[1].set_title('Feral Colony Numbers')

axarr.set_ylabel('Colonies Surviving')

axarr.set_xlabel('Years')

plt.show()
```

I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set_ylabel'.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the subplots **axis labels separately**. i.e.

```
# subplot 1
axarr[0].set_ylabel('Colonies Surviving')
axarr[0].set_xlabel('Years')

# subplot 2
axarr[1].set_ylabel('Colonies Surviving')
axarr[1].set_xlabel('Years')
```

instead of

```
axarr.set_ylabel('Colonies Surviving')
axarr.set_xlabel('Years')
```